# Setting resource in XMPP Facebook chat

Tags: facebook, xmpp

When we connect to googletalk using xmpp, we can set the resource attribute, and can thus identify whether the user is logged in from android, pc etc.

I was wondering if there is any similar way to specify/identify device in facebook chat API.
When I connect with xmpp, facebook do all the internal transation and erase off my resource value.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not what the resource identifier is meant for, even if many users or software put human readable text there. For security reason the resource should be unpredictable.

Use Service Discovery:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html

Comment: I stumbled upon xep-0030 shortly after asking this question. Unfortunately, Facebook chat as of yet doesn't support such standard xep's. It gives a 'service unavailable' error. Even Googletalk uses server supplied values in the reply, and doesn't really allow the client to add any info :-/

Comment: There is no special server support required for this. They only need to route the stanza from one client to another.
Did you send the packet to the correct full jid (jid with resource)?

Comment: You are right, the server routes the Iq requests correctly! But this doesn't seem to be working with facebook. I am sending Iq addressed to the translated jid (of the form -12345678@chat.facebook.com), but it doesn't seem to be reaching the other end..

Comment: iqs must be addressed to full jids (with resources)

Comment: Facebook XMPP does not support arbitrary stanzas, so this is unlikely to work.

Comment: Exactly. I looked into everything out there and seems like Facebook chat API is very restricted. About full jid, I couldn't see a resource part in the roster while using DIGEST-MD5 method. May be I should also try X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM method and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: the resource comes with the presence, not with the roster. But they even don't support iq stanzas as Zash said then there is no chance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XEP-0115](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html): Entity Capabilities.  Mark up your presence stanzas with caps.  Pre-load the caps cache of all of your clients with the disco#info describing each.  This will just barely work for your clients on FaceBook, and will interoperate really well on other systems.

Please read the XEP multiple times.  Almost everyone misunderstands it at first.